# Cannot locate a static file. I get an error that 'STATIC_ROOT' is not set

Tags: python, django, nginx

### What I want to do

I'm trying to deploy my Django app using AWS (EC2), nginx, and gunicorn. The current goal is to place the static files in the directory /usr/share/nginx/html/static.

### Problem that is occurring

I created /usr/share/nginx/html/static and then ran  `python manage.py collectstatic` command.

I had set STATIC_ROOT in settings.py to STATIC_ROOT='/usr/share/nginx/html/static' before, so I thought I could use the collectstatic command to collect static files from within the Django project and place them in /usr/share/nginx/html/static. However, that wasn't the case. Instead I got an error saying `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.` Could you please explain why this is so?

I have tried some suggested solutions over the internet but the problem still exists. I’d be really appreciated if you could reply to me.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ymoj.png)

['STATIC_ROOT'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp36M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried created a Django project and define STATIC_ROOT='/usr/share/nginx/html/static

The only problem I face is

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/nginx/html/static/admin'
```

After fixing permission it worked.

So As is see you are running collectstatic with a specific setting file(`private_diary.settings`) make sure static root is defined in that file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I changed permission in the static directory and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permission in the static directory

And make sure to include STATIC_ROOT in your settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/usr/share/nginx/html/static"

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "/usr/share/nginx/html/static"
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I changed permission in the static directory and it worked.